# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in Pentaho Data Integration

Tags: java, oracle, pdi

I am using **PDI 5.4.0.1-130** version with which I run a transformation from within java.

My problem is that from time to time my integration tests are throwing this exception...

Any advice is welcomed

```
 org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
 An error occurred executing SQL:
 SELECT *
 FROM "ProcessType"

  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:745)
  at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run (RunThread.java:62)
  at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableinput.TableInput.processRow (TableInput.java:138)
  at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableinput.TableInput.doQuery (TableInput.java:224)
  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.openQuery (Database.java:1732)
  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.getRowInfo (Database.java:2252)
  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.getValueFromSQLType (Database.java:2306)
  at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next (ArrayList.java:851)
  at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification (ArrayList.java:901)

    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.openQuery(Database.java:1736)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableinput.TableInput.doQuery(TableInput.java:224)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableinput.TableInput.processRow(TableInput.java:138)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.getValueFromSQLType(Database.java:2306)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.getRowInfo(Database.java:2252)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.openQuery(Database.java:1732)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have posted a bug on pentaho's jira and seems that it was already reported

http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-13789

upgrading to 6.0.0 version comes with this fix.